# div into array using map function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I m adding child divs of main div into array by id
but couldn't get what is the problem.......?
after adding into array i waant to send to ajax to write in csv

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
        <p>Click the button to convert the array into a String.</p>
        <div id='main'>
            <div id='a'>
                dab
            </div>
            <div id='b'>
                nav
            </div>
        </div>

        <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

        <p id="demo"></p>

        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                var array = $('#main id').map(function() {
                    return $(this).val();
                }).get();
                array.toString();
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = array;
            }
        </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `val()` gets the value of an input, you have no elements with a value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `attribute selector` properly,

```
var array = $('#main [id]').map(function() {
   return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

Also `.val()` is a jquery function is specially for the elements which yields `value` property when accessing it on a node object. So when you want to access the content inside a `div`, you have to use `.text()`

Comment: @HamasMalik You have to configure your fiddle properly(add jquery library, wrap code in header tag). https://jsfiddle.net/L4yL7hjL/1/